# CodeIgniter allow hyphen in url?

Tags: codeigniter-3

I have tried the following, but unfortunately it does not work:

```
$route['request-guide'] = "request_guide";
```

In my application/core I created MY_Router.php, but this is also not working.

```
<?php defined('BASEPATH') || exit('No direct script access allowed');
class MY_Router extends CI_Router {
function _set_request ($seg = array())
 {
// The str_replace() below goes through all our segments
// and replaces the hyphens with underscores making it
// possible to use hyphens in controllers, folder names and
// function names
 parent::_set_request(str_replace('-', '_', $seg));

 }
 }
 ?>
```

Comment: Look at `$config['permitted_uri_chars']` in your `config.php` file.

Answer (score 0):

Open file /application/config/routes.php and add following line in the route array.

```
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = TRUE;
```

It will automatically translate your MY_CONTROLLER to MY-CONTROLLER or in small letters.